# Heatmap like plot with Lattice

Tags: r, lattice

I can not figure out how the lattice `levelplot` works. I have played with this now for some time, but could not find reasonable solution.

Sample data:

```
Data <- data.frame(x=seq(0,20,1),y=runif(21,0,1))
Data.mat <- data.matrix(Data)
```

Plot with levelplot:

```
rgb.palette <- colorRampPalette(c("darkgreen","yellow", "red"), space = "rgb")

levelplot(Data.mat, main="", xlab="Time", ylab="", col.regions=rgb.palette(100),   
          cuts=100, at=seq(0,1,0.1), ylim=c(0,2), scales=list(y=list(at=NULL)))
```

This is the outcome:

[image]

Since, I do not understand how this levelplot really works, I can not make it work. What I would like to have is the colour strips to fill the whole window of the corresponding `x` (Time).

> Alternative solution with other method.

Basically, I'm trying here to plot the increasing risk over time, where the red is the highest risk = 1. I would like to visualize the sequence of possible increase or clustering risk over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?levelplot` we're told that if the first argument is a matrix then "'x' provides the
    'z' vector described above, while its rows and columns are
    interpreted as the 'x' and 'y' vectors respectively.", so

```
> m = Data.mat[, 2, drop=FALSE]
> dim(m)
[1] 21  1
> levelplot(m)
```

plots a levelplot with 21 columns and 1 row, where the levels are determined by the values in m. The formula interface might look like

```
> df <- data.frame(x=1, y=1:21, z=runif(21))
> levelplot(z ~ y + x, df)
```

(these approaches do not quite result in the same image).

Comment: Yes, I played with the second option you have shown. The only problem was that I assigned constant always below 1. That gave me weird answers. If one would leave out the constant 1, that would not work as desired. I didn't understood what the constant role really is. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don't know much about `lattice`, but I noted your "Alternative solution with other method", so may I suggest another possibility:

```
library(plotrix)
color2D.matplot(t(Data[ , 2]), show.legend = TRUE, extremes = c("yellow", "red"))
```

Heaps of things to do to make it prettier. Still, a start. Of course it is important to consider the breaks in your time variable. In this *very* simple attempt, regular intervals are implicitly assumed, which happens to be the case in your example.

**Update**
Following the advice in the 'Details' section in `?color2D.matplot`: "The user will have to adjust the plot device dimensions to get regular squares or hexagons, especially when the matrix is not square". Well, well, quite ugly solution.

```
par(mar = c(5.1, 4.1, 0, 2.1))
windows(width = 10, height = 2.5)
color2D.matplot(t(Data[ , 2]),
                show.legend = TRUE,
                axes = TRUE,
                xlab = "",
                ylab = "",
                extremes = c("yellow", "red"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is close what I need but as you noted to be a start. I will wait a little bit longer and see what else would be offered here. Would close this issue within days. Thanks again.

Comment: @Max I updated to script slightly to make the squares somewhat prettier.